# Multiple suscriber suscribes single queue and consumes messages according to its set property

Tags: rabbitmq-exchange

actually I am start use of RabbitMQ in my Projects and I am trying while consumer consumes data its consume that only related to this because in queue multiple records is there so how can I Acheive this

some tips to do that activity